# How to fire Jquery Datatable child control events in angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular

We are using JQuery Datable for our Angular 4 project.Data displaying properly.Edit button events are not firing properly.

I am getting the error "Unhandled exception at line 3, column 1 in script block

0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'onEditClick' is undefined"

while clicking the edit button.

Please see the below code for reference

this.http.get(this.appService.baseUrl + 'api/ServiceType').subscribe(result => {

```
        this.serviceTypes = result.json() as IServiceTypeSummary[];

        //$(".log-data-table").DataTable();

        $(".log-data-table").DataTable({

            "data": this.serviceTypes,

            scrollY: "500px",

            destroy: true,

            scrollX: true,

            scrollCollapse: true,

            autoWidth: true,

            paging: true, 

            "columns": [

                { data: "serviceTypeId" },

                { data: "name"},

                { data: "status" },


                {
```

data: null, orderable: true, "name": "columnName",

render: function (data, type, row) {

```
                        return   '<a class="btn btn-primary"
```

onclick="onEditClick(data);">Edit ';

```
                    }

                }


            ]

        });

    }, error => console.error(error));


}

onEditClick(data): void {

    alert(data);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats normal. You should use arrow function otherwise it will not work. Let me explain. Your JQueryDataTable doesnt know anything about your typescript function. So using arrow function will let him know that there is a function called. So your code should be

```
render: (data, type, row) => {
   return '<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onEditClick(data);">Edit </a>';
}
```

But I am not sure function will be triggered, anyway just give a try and let us know. The best option will be to create a function that will trigger `onEditClick()` on button click. You can add a class name to the button and with jQuery you will trigger the function. I already did it once and here is how I did it using jQuery

```
render: (data, type, row) => {
 return '<a class="btn btn-primary edit-button" >Edit </a>';
}

ngOnInit(){
 this.triggerUpdate()
}

triggerUpdate(){
 jQuery("table#datatableTag").on('click', 'a.edit-button', (evt) => { 
    var row = jQuery(evt.currentTarget).closest('tr');
    var data = jQuery('table#datatableTag').dataTable().fnGetData(row);
    this.onEditClick(data);
 })
}
```